# Incorrect syntax near 'tuition'

Tags: vb.net

```
openconnection()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) - Val(TextBox17.Text) > 0 Then
            cmd = New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
        Query = "UPDATE Students" &
            "set tuition = '" & Val(TextBox1.Text) - Val(TextBox17.Text) & "'" &
            "where id = '" & Form9.TextBox10.Text & "'"
            cmd.CommandText = Query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Sucessfully paid account")
            Form1.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If
```

Can someone help me find the problem? It says syntax error near "tuition". If someone can pinpoint the problem id highly appreciate. Thanks

Comment: `Can someone help me find the problem`  which one?  use SQL parameters, dont use one global connection, dispose of your COmmand object(s), dont use `Val` and if `id` is a number, dont pass text.

Comment: Also, you have arithmetic surrounded by single quotes...that won't execute the math and you end up trying to insert chars into a number column

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be a space between Students and set:

```
"UPDATE Students " &
        "set tuition
```